# How do I find the difference between normal text and the JSON encoded text in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have used [JSON::Any](http://search.cpan.org/dist/JSON-Any) in my program to transfer the hash between client and server.

I faced one problem, I want to find whether the text (sent by client) is normal text or JSON encoded text.

Can anyone please tell me how to find,

without checking, I got some error in server side and it is closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it without checking. The most simple approach is to just do the decoding and then handle the exception.

```
use JSON::Any;
use Try::Tiny;

my $perl_data;
for my $perhaps_json (
    q(this won't decode), q({"how":"ever", "this":"will"}),
) {
    try {
        $perl_data = JSON::Any->jsonToObj($perhaps_json);
    } catch {
        warn "decoding failed: $_\n";
    }
}
say "Even with invalid input, I did not crash!";
__END__
decoding failed: 'true' expected, at character offset 0 (before "this won't decode") at .../lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.1/JSON/Any.pm line 529.

Even with invalid input, I did not crash!
```

Comment: Yeah. I tried this handling $SIG{__DIE__} signal even though I handle the signal, server killed. my main intention is to, server should not down for any reason.

But your Idea is nice. I didn't think of another module.

Thanks for your answer. 

And alternate Answers are always welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are sending JSON in HTTP messages, you should be using the correct [JSON MIME type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type). When you get the request, check the MIME type. When you send the response, set the right MIME type.

If the user-agent is using `text/plain` for everything, you're stuck with [daxim's 'try it and see' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583355/how-do-i-find-the-difference-between-normal-text-and-the-json-encoded-text-in-per/2583981#2583981).

Comment: Actually, I didn't use any HTTP messages. I am using normal TCP socket program to transfer the messages ( hash is the data structure for that messages ).

Comment: Maybe you should change that then. Meta data in your data transfers can tell the other side what it is getting.